# Роман и роман

Tags: значение-слов, омонимы

Как известно, роман - это форма литературного произведения, охватывающая большой промежуток времени. Одна из самых крупных форм, насколько я помню. Но при этом "роман" - это любовные отношения. Например, "у них завязался служебный роман".
Скажите, пожалуйста, какая связь? Означает ли это, что в романе, как литературном произведении, в обязательном порядке должна быть любовная линия, а если таковой нет, то пусть будет хоть десятитомник, но это все равно будет повесть? Либо роман в литературе и роман между мужчиной и женщиной - это просто омонимы и друг к другу отношения не имеют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из словаря:РОМАН 1.Большое повествовательное произведение, обычно в прозе, со сложным, разветвлённым сюжетом. Научно-фантастический р. Исторический р. Психологический, бытовой р. Р. Л. Н. Толстого "Война и мир". "Евгений Онегин" - р. в стихах. Читать романы. Создать р.2. Разг. Любовные отношения между мужчиной и женщиной. Завести р. с кем-л.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

В русском языке название этого литературного жанра употребляется с середины 18 века (заимствование из фр. языка).

Впервые же романы появились в средние века, от romanicus -  римский, латинский. Так назывались произведения, написанные не на классической латыни, а на разговорном латинском, а также на возникших на основе латыни романских языках (французском, испанском, итальянском).

Обычно такие книги повествовали о любовных приключениях, отсюда второе значение слова как отношения между мужчиной и женщиной.